# Need T-SQL help in Sql Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables `Employee` and `EmployeeLog` (with the same columns except `LogCreatedDate`)

Columns are something like this:

```
EmployeeID, EmployeeName, LastModifiedBy, ModifiedDate,
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC bla-bla-bla
```

I need T-SQL which give me output as shown in this table.

**ResultSet 1:**

[image]

On every `Employee` table update I insert a new row in `EmployeeLog` table with current values.

`EmployeeLog` table contains multiple rows for each `EmployeeID` so I need previous and current value in column that is modified.

So my first step is that I fetch TOP 2 record order by `LogCreatedDate DESC`. Now what should I do for getting output as shown in table?

**ResultSet 2:**
[image]

Thanks

Comment: i have TOP 2 record order by LogCreatedDate DESC,now how to compare these two rows and arrange as per shown table in image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeLog TABLE
(
    EmployeeID int,
    EmployeeName varchar(50),
    LastModifiedBy varchar(50),
    ModifiedDate datetime,
    ColumnA varchar(50),
    ColumnB varchar(50),
    ColumnC varchar(50),
    LogCreatedDate datetime
)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeLog VALUES (1, 'A', 'A', '2012-02-07', 'A', 'B', 'C', '2012-02-07')
INSERT INTO @EmployeeLog VALUES (1, 'B', 'B', '2012-02-06', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', '2012-02-06')

;
WITH    Basics AS
(
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LogCreatedDate DESC) as Entry
        FROM    @EmployeeLog 
),      PivotTable AS
(
        SELECT  EmployeeID,
                LastModifiedBy,
                ModifiedDate,
                'ColumnA' ColumnName,
                ColumnA ColumnValue,
                LogCreatedDate,
                Entry
        FROM Basics
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  EmployeeID,
                LastModifiedBy,
                ModifiedDate,
                'ColumnB' ColumnName,
                ColumnB ColumnValue,
                LogCreatedDate,
                Entry
        FROM Basics
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  EmployeeID,
                LastModifiedBy,
                ModifiedDate,
                'ColumnC' ColumnName,
                ColumnC ColumnValue,
                LogCreatedDate,
                Entry
        FROM Basics
)
SELECT  [Current].LastModifiedBy, [Current].ModifiedDate,
        Previous.EmployeeID, Previous.ColumnName,
        Previous.ColumnValue [Previous Value],
        [Current].ColumnValue [Current Value]
FROM    PivotTable Previous
JOIN    PivotTable [Current]
    ON  Previous.EmployeeID = [Current].EmployeeID AND
        Previous.ColumnName = [Current].ColumnName AND
        Previous.Entry = [Current].Entry + 1
```

Comment: thanks Rubens.thanks a lot. Its really help me out.Its awesome.Its exactly as per my need.                                               +1 for your response.

Comment: I have one more thing to do is that now i want to filter out this resultset so that it should display only those records that have changed column value i.e eliminate the records with the same Previous and Current value

Comment: Please see the resultset 2 in my question for reference.so now it should filter out rowno 1 & 3 NOT 2.